# What's the difference between $(this) and this.$

Tags: jquery

($ of course meaning jQuery)

For example what's the difference between
$(this).addClass('className'); and this.$.addClass('className');

Comment: I've never seen this.$.addClass('className')

Comment: @RobertMcKee - That is because it doesn't exist :) `addClass` is part of the prototype and as a result isn't available when the constructor hasn't been called.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of difference.

*In the first example*

```
$(this).addClass('className');
```

you are calling the jQuery constructor with `this` and then using the jQuery API to add a class to it. I am assuming that `this` is an element and not just the window (which is what `this` generally refers to without any scope).

*In the second example*

```
this.$.addClass('className')
```

you are accessing the native element (assuming that this isn't window here) and then attempting to find the `$` property on that element. The property will not exist and so there will be an error caused. If you were to use this version with `this` as `window` then `$` would be a property (as jQuery is "global"), however `addClass` is part of the jQuery prototype and as a result will not be present there either as the constructor was never called.

In conclusion, the first one is proper, and the second one doesn't really make any sense to use for multiple reasons.

Comment: `$(this)` means the value of `this` in the current context is converted into a jQuery object and can therefor be used with methods like `addClass()` and such

Comment: @brroshan - You are mistaken. `$()` calls the jQuery function which internally calls the jQuery constructor. Once the constructor is called the prototype is available. The value passed, `this` in this case, is the element which is placed into the jQuery object's array like structure. It is not "converted" into a jQuery object, the jQuery object contains a reference to it. It cannot be "used with methods", the jQuery object's constructor places those methods on the instance of the function object and when those methods are called they act on the elements in the array-like structure.

Comment: Ah, i stand corrected. Thanks for the clarification :)